# mongoid - Dynamic date/time attribute - MultiParameter Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model named `Form`, which get fields as per user requirement, eg if user puts text field in the form then a attribute is created in Form model for storing string data.

Similarly I want to store date/time and datetime values. So I added

`include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes`

in the form model, because date and time values are submitted from for in multiple attributes.

But I get `Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes::Errors::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors` exception in the controller create action, on the line `@form = Form.new(params[:form])`

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(params[:form])
  if @form.save
    redirect_to(form_path(@form))
  else
    redirect_to :action => "new"
  end
end
```

How do I get through this.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `Form` class so it looks like the one below.

```
class Form
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The ruby driver can only serialize Time objects. That might be your problem.